# Trying to take and use a value assigned to a string in a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I've assigned values to strings in my combobox however I can't seem to get the variable to get the value selected.

Example:

```
this.selectquest.Items.AddRange(new Level[] {
  new Level() {Name = "Level 41", Value = 1476088},
  new Level() {Name = "Level 52", Value = 6000000},
  new Level() {Name = "Level 53", Value = 7000000}});
```

I want to take the Value (based on the combobox selection) and set it to a variable:

```
int Value = ptexp;
```

Then I want to do math with it like this:

```
int ttlvl = ptexp / tlvl;
```

However, when I do that it only gives me the number 0. If I do the reverse then it gives an error saying that it tried to divide by 0.

Additional info:

This is what worked:

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    op = "X";
    clvl = int.Parse(currentlevel.Text);
    currentlevel.Text = "";

    cexp = int.Parse(currentexp.Text);
    currentexp.Text = "";

    mexp = int.Parse(mobsexp.Text);
    mobsexp.Text = "";

    if (op == "X") 
        tlvl = clvl - cexp;
    int ttlvl = tlvl / ptexp;
    turnstolvl.Text = ttlvl.ToString();

}

private void selectquest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectquest.DisplayMember = "Name";
    var v = selectquest.SelectedItem as Level;
    int Value = (selectquest.SelectedItem as Level).Value;
    ptexp = Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the selected value of your combobox to get at it:

```
var selectedValue = (Level)selectquest.SelectedItem;
int value = selectedValue.Value;
```

You could do this on this event: comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

UPDATE:

If you want value to equal the selection do this in the event:

```
int value = (selectquest.SelectedItem as Level).Value; 
ptexp = value;
```

Comment: This is what I currently have there:

           `selectquest.DisplayMember = "Name";
            var v = selectquest.SelectedItem as Level;
            int x = v.Value;`

Comment: @Advancin That will work fine. You can set the DisplayMember in the designer also

Comment: Ok, here's what I've got: edited original post with more info.

Comment: I'm trying to use it but it's not working. That's what I'm saying. I set `Value = ptexp` and then I'm trying to `ptexp / tlvl = int ttlvl`

Comment: You mean int ttlvl = ptexp / tlvl; Still no idea what not working is supposed to mean. Try sticking a breakpoint on the line and debugging through the code to identify the values of variables? Saying it's not working is just not good enough, not enough to help you at all

Comment: Ok, what I mean by "it's not working" is that when I run the program it's saying that ptexp has a value of 0. I have values stored for each selection in the combobox. The `Value` should equal the selection and then be assigned to the `ptexp` however it's not doing that and I don't know why.

Comment: @Advancin If you want value to equal the selection do this in the event: int value = (selectquest.SelectedItem as Level).Value; Then: ptexp = value;

Comment: Updated the original post with the working solution.